# Advent of Code 2021 Day 4: Play Bingo against a Giant Squid

Tags: c++, object-oriented, programming-challenge, c++20

[This is my first post here - though I have been lurking in the back reading, plussing, and hopefully learning for over two years]

Below is my solution for ***Advent of Code 2021 Day 4***, where you are **playing bingo against a giant squid**.
You are given a set of bingo cards, and the list of numbers that will be drawn; the target for **part 1** is to identify the bingo card that ***wins first***, and for **part 2**, the card that ***wins last***. For more details, check [this link](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/4).

Some remarks:

- this is supposed to be developed against the clock. Therefore, reusability is not a very important consideration.
- error checking is not required, and not done. Bad input will blow everything apart; please ignore this.
- I work in a C++20 environment (but didn't necessarily use any features of it). I marked it C++20 because if C++20 offers something I missed, I want to learn about it.

***What I am looking for:***

- what is bad / poor / smelly?
- what could be improved?
- what could I do better using the C++20 feature set? I know about the  capabilities, but didn't see any way to take advantage of it.

Here is the include BingoCard.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

constexpr size_t BingoCardSize = 5;
using Card = std::array<int, BingoCardSize* BingoCardSize>;

class BingoCard
{
public:
  static BingoCard Create(std::istream& input);                 // construct by reading the numbers from input
  int DrawNumbers(const std::vector<int>& n) noexcept;          // draw numbers till 'bingo'
  int GetRemainder() const noexcept;                            // get sum of numbers remaining after 'bingo'

private:
  BingoCard(Card& n) noexcept : number(n) {}                    // constructor
  bool HasBingo() const noexcept;                               // check for 'bingo'


private:
  const Card number;                                            // numbers on the bingo card
  std::array<bool, BingoCardSize * BingoCardSize> hit{ false }; // flags if a number was hit
};
```

Here the class  code in BingoCard.cpp:

```
#include "BingoCard.h"

BingoCard BingoCard::Create(std::istream& input)
{
  Card n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); ++i) input >> n[i];
  return BingoCard(n);
}

bool BingoCard::HasBingo(void) const noexcept  // check for 'bingo'. note: diagonals are NOT considered 'bingo'
{
  for (int i = 0; i < BingoCardSize; ++i)
  {
    bool row{ true };
    bool col{ true };
    for (int j = 0; j < BingoCardSize; ++j)
    {
      row &= hit[BingoCardSize * i + j];   // check along row
      col &= hit[i + BingoCardSize * j];   // check along column
    }
    if (row || col) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int BingoCard::DrawNumbers(const std::vector<int>& draw) noexcept
{
  for (int n = 0; n < draw.size(); ++n)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < BingoCardSize * BingoCardSize; ++j)
    {
      if (number[j] == draw[n])
      {
        hit[j] = true;
        if (HasBingo()) return n;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return draw.size();
}

int BingoCard::GetRemainder(void) const noexcept
{
  int sum{ 0 };
  for (int i = 0; i < BingoCardSize * BingoCardSize; ++i)
  {
    if (!hit[i]) sum += number[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

and here the main program:

```
#include "BingoCard.h"

void AoC2021_04(std::istream& input)
{
  std::string line{};

  // read all numbers drawn during the game
  std::vector<int> draw{};
  getline(input, line);
  std::istringstream str(line);
  int z0{ 0 };
  while (str >> z0) {
    draw.emplace_back(z0);
    char comma{};
    str >> comma; // read the comma and ignore it
  }

  // read all Bingocards
  std::vector<BingoCard> board{};
  while (getline(input, line))     // the success of this blank line read means there is another board coming
  {
    board.emplace_back(BingoCard::Create(input));
  }

  // find the BingoCards with the earliest [Part 1] and latest [Part 2] 'bingo' (that is, the minimum / maximum of DrawNumbers return value)
  int min{ std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
  int mini{ -1 };
  int max{ 0 };
  int maxi{ -1 };
  for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); ++i)
  {
    auto n = board[i].DrawNumbers(draw);
    if (n < min)
    {
      min = n;
      mini = i;
    }
    if (n > max)
    {
      max = n;
      maxi = i;
    }
  }

  int z1 = board[mini].GetRemainder() * draw[min];  // AoC solution is min BingoCard's remainder times the winning number
  std::cout << "AoC2021 Day 4 Part 1: " << z1 << '\n';

  int z2 = board[maxi].GetRemainder() * draw[max];  // AoC solution is max BingoCard's remainder times the winning number
  std::cout << "AoC2021 Day 4 Part 2: " << z2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  AoC2021_04(std::cin);
}
```

my input data (if you go to AoC and log in, you get a different input - everyone gets a slightly different one. I am quite sure the code above works for any input):

```
37,60,87,13,34,72,45,49,61,27,97,88,50,30,76,40,63,9,38,67,82,6,59,90,99,54,11,66,98,23,64,14,18,4,10,89,46,32,19,5,1,53,25,96,2,12,86,58,41,68,95,8,7,3,85,70,35,55,77,44,36,51,15,52,56,57,91,16,71,92,84,17,33,29,47,75,80,39,83,74,73,65,78,69,21,42,31,93,22,62,24,48,81,0,26,43,20,28,94,79

66 78  7 45 92
39 38 62 81 77
 9 73 25 97 99
87 80 19  1 71
85 35 52 26 68

47 38 84 53 16
66  3 63 92 94
71 41 59  1 87
17 67 62 73 33
69 12 26 82 55

89 94 65 57  6
27 77 60 19 83
72 58  0 29 91
33 75 50 64 87
24 88 32 93 38

35 82  7 49 43
58  8 56 54  6
74 53 98 59 84
 4 40 11 67 14
89  1 44 51 45

44 51 57 75 19
33 54 24 96  1
30  0 45 47 38
58 78 17 74 14
91 60 32 67 10

72 91 61 45 49
68 67 31 69 96
92 52  9 34 36
16 77 62 55 41
42 88 53  4 15

68 98 73 81 41
36 43 87 48 95
55 62  8 12 30
23 34 59 72 85
38  7 16 13 79

66 98 23 69 89
71 84 79 14 53
10 62 60 44 28
49 43 29 45 75
72 94  5 64  3

27 99 41 10 91
 2 94 16 85 75
25 95 15 34 36
90 72 76 20 29
55 18 93 53 69

84 87 16 80 64
48 45 63 53 25
10 44 65 58 59
94 31 41 35 89
42 29 71 69 61

63 44 74 33  3
65 47 90 52 38
 9 13 91  4 45
26 39 94 68 93
56 31 41 59 32

17  6 85 74 19
58 93  9 92 31
90 69  2 87 11
67 94 53 66 30
15 41 59 51 45

 7 59 76 14 15
51  3 88 17  2
42 39 98 84 65
54 48  9 56 74
68  5  1 24 13

55 34 94 50 28
 8 14 93 64 52
92 62  9 51 38
31 74 73 24 59
33 65  7 75 32

30 93 48 17 33
67  7  5  0 69
54 76 52  1 87
99 73 50 25 16
13 20 41 77 62

54  0 33 23 75
50  4 29 18 94
14  8 38 48 53
84 13 12 91 83
69 78 55 47 26

30 65 70 51  1
22 53 86 46 89
99 79 20 24 64
18 92 82  0 68
57 33 61 12 83

22 47 21 38 57
41 63 61 95 79
 7 52 87 71 14
40 45 92 73 48
42  0 26 94  5

90 98 47 85 52
19 44 48 59 88
93 81  7 16 63
 1 45 84 11 24
78 27 62 77 37

34  2  6  3 56
48 47 12 58 76
89 78 30 75 20
91 39 97 69 28
96 64 32 61 67

62 25 53 56 97
42 34 24 64 95
17 35  7 79 68
30 74 54 78  3
88 66 18 38 90

63 45 80 89 76
39 57 71 25 79
 6  3 28 94 34
82 18 95 42 33
96 36 27 83 66

20 87 59 86 21
14 61  7 23 56
 5 33 91  0  1
97 65 82 95 72
18 26 35 47 69

86 65 41 97 40
 2 73 68 34  3
88 71 79 70 95
48 62  1 50 77
13 67 20 15 55

98 16 93 30 24
39 11 56 13  3
14 83 76 58 60
73 81 63 88 92
74 96 51 43 77

 4 12 43 46 53
34 37 50 60 56
96 98 10 65 38
40 24 80 77 73
23 67 84 64 13

 5 19 85  1 58
41 15 44 57 22
 2 66 80 94 71
40 55 89 79  0
56 81 23 30 24

 0 29 94  4 68
81  2 20 95 43
49 40 37 30 96
19 23 42 26 85
61 17 12 72 88

64 26 61 32 68
80 24 31 67 49
72 15 88 98 50
73 55 86 38 10
87 34 52 29 63

76 61 36 54 10
63 56 75 67 29
11  9 41  4 43
83 88 45 93 74
72 70 94 60 98

44 99 39  5 23
53 69 68 60 83
81 72  1 97 20
43 96 91 11 32
51  7  8 86 25

62 36 39 20  5
52 59  6 74 95
 2 83 44 43 66
96 55 79 42 37
34 32 19  0 90

84  8 65 35 78
57 83  4 82 36
 3 29 74 60 90
86 47 53 26 10
52 51 40 32  6

69 32 77 72 44
34 54 82 94 23
 1 60  2 11 36
17 52  0 73 31
 5 90 24 21 53

42 24 18 44  5
74 19 76 62 34
61 66  4 77 47
92 94 78 39 97
25 91 11 22 23

11 87 83 93  8
 7 73 85 84  3
65 16 71 12 44
88 61 54 19 97
72 57 80 59 45

30 55  1 62 39
31 45 34  6 43
68 93 38 57 60
70 32  5 95 92
35 83 66 36 91

76 89 54 36 21
99 28 62 78 73
17 72 96 13 91
79 65 37 81 14
33 86 31 11 25

 3 93 37 88 47
 4  6 19 87 30
76 22 33 69 64
36 52 60 82 53
39  5 61 67 90

28  6 59 61 75
40  4 65 43 93
41 32 60 89 18
22 11 12  9  0
26 15 78 90 30

 8 87 74 70 76
45 43 63 84 25
18 68 92  4 31
66 22 29 71 91
15 50 64 52  1

 3 93 25 71 43
45 48 52  4 94
36 34 47 74 97
12 27 64 14 80
41 17 21 32 88

76 62 68 24  0
97 43 37  3 79
65 25 52 28 20
29 18 90 89 48
35 66 19 53 82

57 98 86 69 24
55 74 49 12 35
68 50 70 38 75
82 56 73  5 89
90 10 15 14 95

98 86 47 87 81
62 51  3 79 10
60 39 61  9 77
36 50 89 49 88
63 95  1 15 69

72 71 51 33 23
12 35 97 34 99
 4 32 36 88 80
 5 17  3 56  1
44 19 47 98 26

55 56 75  5 74
 4 86 60 67 68
21 45 40 17  2
43 39 20 88 33
24 70 58 13 98

34 28 86 65 80
82 23 98 91  0
61 62 43 51 49
39 10 58  1 11
 8 83 17 97 31

 7 96  2 18 26
15 86 34 76 61
75 93 68  3 83
63 37 85  8 74
11 51 32 14 23

25 33 24 86 75
63 73 97 37 47
76 72 34 81 27
93 91 70 20 98
11 94 64 28  6

70 86 59 78 95
47 18 64 40 68
49 55 20 12 53
60 76 35 83 50
32 73 91 46 28

31 21 92 97 89
14 82 51  1 62
43 58 90 18 24
56 79 54 35 48
29 39 45 86 66

62 74 81 27 23
28 92 66 86 29
98 95 14 35 11
13 69 70 64 79
51 80 87 96 85

69 15 37 95 29
 6 45 20 17 36
62 42  1 77 59
25 44 72 35 31
70 73 86 89 97

81 88 82 99 13
53 87  2 29 47
36 94 48 95 65
96 42 92 61 60
86 33 83 52 12

32  4 52 54 24
28 77 58 80 16
62 82 59  6 66
63 72 91 41 29
36 22 68  0 31

38 58 51 77 26
80  5 90 30 20
33 14 54 53  0
76 74 63 84 15
45 73 41 29 69

28 31 47 97 58
69  7 86 40 57
45  1 11 84 54
29  9 95 93 88
12  5 79 76 77

93  7 60 75 12
49 64 20 46 10
 3 23 76 42 47
 9 22  6 34 87
41 37 66 45 48

 9 53 64 37 83
89 43 91 30 36
39 22 69 79 42
31 28 55 40 54
 7 24 44 84 46

81 75 15 89 31
11 13 12  5 10
94 80 22 68  3
27 60 42 65 58
40 82 17 92 73

16 40 98 33 41
79 72  2 77 86
14 32 85 74 50
11 49 62 56  9
69 20 12 19 60

95 72 61 54 92
10  0  1 84 99
88 62 13 18 86
89 59 60 29 78
55 98 27 91 87

58 37 49 43 76
14  3 65 13  2
92 20  6 73  5
96 53 82 95 99
15 83 80 26 11

51 71 56 58 95
59 84 46 54 94
 8  7 49 62 83
47 92 32 31 65
48 44 57 25 20

 5  3 26 90 14
61 16 44  4  0
49  1 52 82 54
60 77 86 43 87
 6 36 73 25 31

32 25 37 18 63
60 65 35 24 34
52 94 12 77 47
99 83  2 30 74
58 38 17 75 56

77 88 70 22 39
 4 14 86 99 50
 5 79  2 78 16
34 46 83 58 13
71 74 21 76 66

25 15 99 79 68
59 95 82 22 53
 0 70 85 73 67
36 10 66  6 32
 1 51 52 40  4

29 49 64 26 18
56 28  9  7 99
20  2 74 71 39
81 94 55 75 16
52 45 35 66 11

42 68 76 37 34
 0 41 86 19 59
 7 46 49 30 88
74 80 24 50 29
96 78 67 61 26

45 96 11 99 44
87 95 32 77 64
 8 31 80  4 34
24 91 90 16 60
13 29 63 67 59

15 55  0 52 54
58 45 62 66 85
91 19 32 16 92
93 59  8 22  2
98 33 31 17 84

28 49 63 81 69
30 45 46 90 26
 4 76 94 93 24
15 16 18 86 62
 2 98 89 44 67

32 35 11  1 38
86 36 70 24 95
59 94 71 99 40
48 64 91 25 57
29 76 68 88 58

45 81 50 20 68
85 91 49 38  9
27  0 58  8 10
59  1 88 19 89
23 29 61 99 12

74 50 41 83  4
33 34 88 23 14
89 39 98 75 37
26 73 80 71 44
52 53 48 84 85

47 35 98 73  9
61  4 71 91 58
65 40 63 36 86
12 30 69 46  2
 6 17 23 32 74

84 87 59 58 65
30 53  7 98 48
71 28  1 77 56
36 88 52 64 89
90 37 94 26 39

25 75 32 48  6
49  7 74 50 62
68 51 72 12 10
94 37 97 69 91
73  9 67 18  1

51 96 71 44  0
97 52  1 77 11
90  9 15 76 24
68  6 57 40 98
47 31 94 82 49

48 31 26 77 14
94 93 27  2 82
11 83 85  9  8
90 69  4 16 22
 5 62 29 57 30

59 46 82 13 53
71 58 67  2 28
73 52 30 97 12
95 34 51 32 38
62 81  5 15 74

82 10 58 84 67
92  5 66 25 83
90 76 21 26 69
39 63 42 11 53
23 61 80 99 48

 8 13 49 63 83
26 48 50 53 43
 1 39 95 60 99
96  7 35 94 10
24 44 65 31 46

87 17 72 71 81
35 56  4 99 59
96 90 37 23 86
34 73 18 19 78
41 10 43 92 80

29  7 37 40 70
72 10 85 74 76
36  9 13 73 82
 4 65 49 77 42
75 24 84 78 39

29  6 94 59 38
99 55  8 66 85
14 43 25 92 67
49 33 87 39 44
 9 61 24 90 75

45 35 78 56 24
53 38 34 92 55
20 44 90 33 83
54 95 71 87 13
40 43 85 88 68

32 80 59 34 22
18  9 12 15 55
85 60 37 64 92
35 39 26 90 50
52 67 58 87  8

90 96 40 14 61
34 33 80 22 38
59 94  3  6  4
 0 71 25  1 20
30 57 48 31 10

50 14 40 48 83
85 80 29 60  2
92 59 86 99 57
46  7 89 66 75
98  6 45 97 51

13 17  0 57  5
29 68 52 11 59
78 63 94 88 89
35 54 74 18  2
28 65 86  1 30

57 46 44 86 62
43 89 81 34 13
32 51  9  6 35
29 52 84  8 88
26 21 17 75 85

14 87 26 22 30
65 78 98  6 60
42 99 19 71 11
68 27 48 52 62
51  1 54 37 74

76 69 37 49 61
20 91 14 31 11
54 40 67 71 15
73 64 85 80 62
 5 10  3 51  7

63 90 54 46 17
16  5  4 56 33
39 41  8 87 80
14 77 26 47 70
15 48  6 10 76

96 95  0 42 56
 3 87 92 18 60
51  7 38  4 91
41 33 80 43 66
61 32 57 84 10

 8 64 76 78 17
55 74 68 47 29
46 84 49 58 93
52 26 32 11 33
24 42 98 27 43

14 19 27 93 16
23 32 74 73 67
68 38  2 22 76
 6 12 94 15 77
64 62 34  3 37
```

Some thoughts about ***design decision*** I made and why I made them. Let me know if you think I should have made them different and why:

- using the 'factory' method Create: I wanted the list of numbers inside the BingoCard to be const, but that disallows to read it from std::cin in the constructor. Alternatively, I could remove the const, and put the Create-code inside the constructor.
- 'hit' array as a member: originally, I modified the numbers on the bingo card to -1 to declare them 'drawn', but that felt poor. The BingoCard should not lose information by getting its numbers overwritten. It worked with the -1 though.
- min/max calculation: I considered using stuff from <algorithm>, but I need more than the min/max values themselves; I also need their indexes. I don't see how I could use them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `HasBingo` works too hard. A hit may create a bingo only along the row and/or column of the square it hits. There is no reason to test *all* of them.

  This observation hints that you may want to have 10 match counts (one per row, and one per column), and declare bingo when one of them reaches 5.
- Representing a card as an `std::map<int, square>` would let you find the hit much faster than scanning the entire card over and over again.
- `DrawNumbers` does *not* belong to `BingoCard`. Consider iterating over the drawn number first, along the lines of:

  ```
    for (auto n: numbers) {
        for (auto b: boards) {
            auto hit = b[n];
            if (hit == b.end() {
                continue;
            }
            if (b.hasBingo(hit) {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
  ```
- The code assumes that a card consists of unique numbers, and the drawn numbers are also unique. However, the problem statement doesn't specify this.  A prudent program must take it into an account.